# Flutter .map() in lists

Tags: flutter

I started to learn Flutter. In stuck in the lists and going though map() and Im getting errors.

So, I have this (I dont know if I can call it a list or a collection of objects)

```
  final list = const [
    {
      'firstText': 'this is the first text',
      'list': [
        {'text': 'list 1'},
        {'text': 'list 2'},
        {'text': 'list 3'},
      ],
    },
    {
      'firstText': 'this is the second text',
      'list': [
        {'text': 'list 4'},
        {'text': 'list 5'},
        {'text': 'list 6'},
      ],
    }
  ];
```

What I want to archive is to grab only the the 'firstText' fields in a loop or the 'list' fields in a loop. And I want also o be able to select by the keys. Ex: only the 'list' with the 'text': list 2.

This is what I'm using

```
final listMap = list.asMap();
print(listMap[1]);
```

**Output**: I/flutter ( 4474): {firstText: this is the second text, list: [{text: list 4}, {text: list 5}, {text: list 6}]}

When I do:

```
print(listMap[1]['firstText']);
```

I got and error. - The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

The other loop im doing is

```
(list).map((key) {
      print(key);
    }).toList();
```

With this I get as **output**:

I/flutter ( 4474): {firstText: this is the first text, list: [{text: list 1}, {text: list 2}, {text: list 3}]}

I/flutter ( 4474): {firstText: this is the second text, list: [{text: list 4}, {text: list 5}, {text: list 6}]}

Here I want also to be able to output only the list[0]['firstText'].
Output: 'this is the first text'

I see that in Flutter/Dart this is not so simple. So I'v looked everywhere and could not find any anwser to help me. I hope my question is not to complicated.

Why I'm using .map()? Well, because I believe we can do loops like this. I know that there are other kinds of loops. But I want to know how to do this with .map().

Thanks

Comment: try `print(listMap[1].firstText);`

Comment: It gives me an error. "The property 'firstText' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      
      var data = list[i].values.first;
      print(data);
      
   }
```

Comment: that's nice. But, what if the 'firstText': 'this is the first text', it's not the first but the second? is there any ".second" way to archieve this?